Facebook reels published privately using the Video API
I am using the Facebook Video API to publish reels to a facebook page. I can sucessfully publish the reel to my page, but it is not visible to anyone else, meaning it is probably private.
I couldn't find any settign or parameter in the API to make the video public
I assume the issue is with permissions? I am using page access tokens for each page, and these are the permissions set for the app:
read_insights
publish_video
pages_show_list
business_management
instagram_basic
instagram_manage_comments
instagram_manage_insights
instagram_content_publish
instagram_manage_messages
pages_read_engagement
pages_manage_metadata
pages_read_user_content
pages_manage_posts
pages_manage_engagement
I hope someone knows what the issue is
I saw that there is another permission: public_profile that should be set, but I just don't see it, it's not in the list of permissions
Do I need to verify the app? (it's in development). I just don't have an actual app, I am using make.com to make api requests to facebook graph api and video api

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

"Do I need to verify the app? (it's in development)." - yes, your app needs to be approved by Facebook in review, and then set "live" - otherwise any content created through it, will only be visible to people with a role in the app.
